# What does: "error in materialized view refresh path" mean?

Tags: oracle12c, materialized-views

I have a query and when I run it I can insert the results fine into the table it needs to go into.

But when we run it as an MV refresh:

```
dbms_mview.refresh(mv, atomic_refresh => transactional) ;
```

we get this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "LINK_OD_IREPORT.R_MV_IN_PLACE", line 26
ORA-06512: at line 1
12008. 00000 -  "error in materialized view refresh path"
*Cause:    Table SNAP$_<mview_name> reads rows from the view
       MVIEW$_<mview_name>, which is a view on the master table
       (the master may be at a remote site).  Any
       error in this path will cause this error at refresh time.
       For fast refreshes, the table <master_owner>.MLOG$_<master>
       is also referenced.
*Action:   Examine the other messages on the stack to find the problem.
       See if the objects SNAP$_<mview_name>, MVIEW$_<mview_name>,
       <mowner>.<master>@<dblink>, <mowner>.MLOG$_<master>@<dblink>
       still exist.
```

Does anyone know what this means?
I've tried querying these and it says they don't exist:
select * from $SNAPSHOT_mv_name;

select * from MVIEW$_mv_name;

Comment: Is `LINK_OD_IREPORT` a package you've written, or something added in 12c? I can't see it in 11g; and very few references in searches, so I'm guessing it's yours. If it is, what is line 26 of the `R_MV_IN_PLACE` procedure doing - since that seems to be throwing the ORA-01722 exception?

Comment: LINK_OD_IREPORT is just the schema name.

The body of r_mv_in_place is basically:

disable_indexes(mv, skip_index) ;
debug('Refreshing ' || mv || ' in-place ...') ;
dbms_mview.refresh(mv, atomic_refresh => transactional) ;

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run that refresh call manually, with the same values for `mv` and `transactional`? If not, can you add the whole of that procedure to the question? Sounds like it might be a bug though, so you probably need to raise a service request with Oracle.

Comment: Yes, I get the same error if I run it manually.